# chrome 87 : No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: google-chrome

When I use chrome version 78, I can pass the custom header key-value to the backend normally, but when I upgrade the kernel to the latest chrome version 87, I get an error when I access the backend java api interface again and it says "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin' header is present on the requested resource."
What am I doing wrong?

`vue : 2.6.11`
`axios: 0.19.2`

Comment: Probably just a security thing that Chrome enforced to bring attention to CORS possible flaws.

Comment: @fluffy This CORS security mechanism in chrome 85 has prevented me from writing web projects locally during the development process. What can I do about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the chrome 85+ security policy problem, by:
Set up a reverse proxy through vue proxy to trick the browser.

Comment: There should not be a need to trick the browser. What web server do you use?

Comment: @yooneskh The server side is nginx with java.

Comment: You can easily add the required header in nginx. i use this snippet to allow cors in my servers. ```add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin * always;
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers * always;
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods * always;```

Answer (score 1):

This is a server-side problem. You should contact the server manager and ask him to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in the responses or do it yourself if server is in your hands).

Comment: I have added the front-end passed key to the "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" in the back-end.

Comment: After my continuous testing. Before chrome version 84 I was able to access the java api normally, when I upgraded chrome to 85 or above, I got the above cross domain error!

Comment: The first attempt to request Request Method: OPTIONS, can be requested successfully, but when the second normal post request backend appears cross-domain, and the request header shows "Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin"